# Mysql Query for displaying result if we get data today else yesterday

Tags: mysql, optimization

I am having a product table and one price table. Price update regularly. Now i want to show price of today and if it was not update today then it show it's previous date price.

How can we perform this using single query?

---

**Included from OP's comments**:

Actually I have two tables
 1) `products`, 2) `product_price` and

We daily enter product price in `product_price` table like

```
+---------+-------+-------+
| Product | Price | Date  |
+---------+-------+-------+
| A       |   33k | 26Jan |
| B       | 34.0k | 26Jan |
| B       | 34.5k | 26Jan |
| A       |   32k | 27Jan |
| A       |   34k | 27Jan |
| C       |  34.5 | 27Jan |
+---------+-------+-------+
```

**Output Expected**:

```
+---------+-------+-------+
| Product | Price | Date  |
+---------+-------+-------+
| A       |   32k | 27Jan |
| B       | 34.0k | 26Jan |
| C       | 34.5k | 27Jan |
+---------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Please show the table structure also.

Comment: So, you just want the latest price.

Comment: Actually i have two tables 1) products 2) product_price and we daily entered product price in product_price table like
product(s3) price(34k) date(27Jan); product(s3) price(34.5k) date(28Jan);product(s3) price(34k) date(29Jan).
Now suppose today is 30 and it's entry not in product_price table
then we need to dispaly 34k which is price of 29.

Comment: Hi Strawberry, Yes i want the same

Comment: Please help me to figure our this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select 
  product, min( price ) as price, date as dt
from 
  product_prices 
where 
  -- use the following if your date field is of type date
  date <= curdate()
  -- use the following if date field is in string format (26Jan)
  -- date <= date_format( curdate(), '%m%b' )
group by 
  product;
```

Comment: @user3239664: like what?

Comment: <pre class="prettyprint lang-html">
Product Price Date
A        1    26Jan
B        1    26Jan
A        2    27Jan
C        3    27Jan 

Output 
A 2 
B 1 
C 3

</pre>

Comment: Could you please let me know how to display code in stackoverflow

Comment: Yes I am updating the post, please check and provide me the solutions

Comment: Sorry, i have updated my post as i am missing one condition(get minimum price) as well. Please try to resolve the updated post

Comment: Hi Ravinder,
Thanks for your quick responses.
Actually my problem is that when we use group by product then their respective records wouldn't be match apart from (Product | Price | Date) some more fields in the table, So after group by respective records mismatch..

Comment: The answer is given based on the given data and expected report fields. If you are expecting more field in the result, you should have posted them along with your question in the posting.